# Lavavel 5.5 отправка данных через форму

Tags: php, laravel

```
@extends('default.index')
@section('sidebar')

    <div class="col-md-9">
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('contact') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Jane Doe">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site">Site</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="site" value="" name="site" placeholder="Site">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Text</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="text" name="text" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>  
@endsection
```

---

**Форма ссылается на маршрут:**

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/contact', ['uses'=>'contactController@show', 'as'=>'contact', 'middleware'=>'contactMiddle']);
```

**При обработке контроллером производится вывод на экран содержимого запроса:**

```
class contactController extends Controller
{
    function show (Request $request) {

        print_r($request->all());
        return view('default.contact');
    }
}
```

---

**Но, при отправке запроса выводится сообщение: **

> The page has expired due to inactivity. 
>   Please refresh and try again.

---

Замена *session driver* на **array** (по умолчанию стоит **file**) результатов не дала.

Comment: Ошибка выпадает при отправке какого запроса? Get или Post?

Comment: через Post...форма же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### В итоге, проблема с выводом данной ошибки решилась путем добавления данного маршрута в качестве исключения в класс, находящийся по адресу:

### app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $except = [
    'route'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Вы забыли включить в форму скрытый Input который содержит CSRF-Token, который защищает от подделки межсайтовых запросов.

Попробуйте добавить в форму отправки запроса функцию {{ csrf_field() }} которая cгенерирует данный input

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: забыл упомянуть, как раз данный imput у меня в форме присутствует...

Comment: покажи, пожалуйста, код представления 'default.contact'

Comment: пожалуйста, отобразил выше

Comment: Сделал так же как у Вас (кроме 'middleware'=>'contactMiddle') - все работает отлично. Могу сделать предположение, что дело в этом посреднике.

Comment: удаление посредника из маршрута не дал результата, да и посредник то был пуст, передавал дальше $request просто...

Comment: Возможно остались старые куки от старого сайта который вы разрабатывали раньше на этом же локальному URL. Попробуйте почистить куки, а еще лучше попробуйте запустить тоже самое на другом браузере.

Comment: Это я уже делал. Чистил кэш. Запускал на другом браузере.

Comment: При обращении данному роуту через get-запрос, выведите на экран токен из сессии, а затем через инспектор кода браузера сравните данный токен с токеном в input hidden. Одинаковы?

Comment: но токен же при каждой загрузке страницы генерируется новый?

Answer (score 0):

Обычно такая ошибка бывает когда выходит время жизни сессии или куки или у вас запрещено создание кук на данной странице, проверьте сначала время жизни сессии в файле `config/session.php`:

```
'lifetime' => Ваше значение в минутах.
```

Но раз вы говорите что отправляете сразу же тогда проблема что отключены куки, проверьте через консоль разработчика или [расширения для Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) к примеру наличия куки - `laravel_session` и `XSRF-TOKEN`.

Лучше проверьте сразу в анонимном режиме, но я склоняюсь к тому что нет кук.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Кук нет.